# Android/Universal Image Loader: Image is not displayed

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I use Universal Image Loader (UIL) to cache and display the images in the List View.

I can't make the images displayed with the following layout for list view's item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to display the image above the image's description. The image's width is the full width of the device, and the image's height is automatically scaled based on the image's width.

With "wrap_content" for both width and height, I can get my images displayed in other projects which don't use UIL. I'm not sure what I did wrong in UIL's configuration (I use the same configuration in their Github's example), but the images are not dsiplayed with the above layout. Actually they are displayed with 0 height. I can make them displayed if I provide a fixed height, something like

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
    />
```

Please let me know if you have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to update the image view's width and height manually based on the bitmap's dimension after it is attached to the image view (onLoadingComplete), the image's dimension is also recalculated to fit the new screen's size when the device is rotated.

If you have any suggestion to improve this solution, of if you have any other solution, please comment. Thanks!

```
private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

    static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        if (loadedImage != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
            if (firstDisplay) {
                FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                displayedImages.add(imageUri);
            }

            // Screen's width will be the width of the image.
            float newWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

            // Get the width and the height of the image.
            int oldWidth = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
            int oldHeight = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

            // Calculate the new height of the image based on the screen's width.
            float newHeight = newWidth * oldHeight / oldWidth;

            // Apply the new width and height values to ImageView.
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) newWidth;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) newHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem,just try to do it like this:

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mImageUrl, mImageView, PhotoUtils.avatarImageOptions,new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            String message = null;
            switch (failReason.getType()) {
                case IO_ERROR:

                    break;
                case DECODING_ERROR:

                    break;
                case NETWORK_DENIED:

                    break;
                case OUT_OF_MEMORY:

                    break;
                case UNKNOWN:

                    break;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mAttacher.update();
        }
    });
```